# 4G Broadband Redundancy

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

A few months ago we installed a 4G antenna onto the side of our house for our mobile internet. We live in a rural area so getting as good a signal as we can is vital. The antenna we got improved the download speeds from 3Mb/s to 40Mb/s.

However, we know we are competing with neighbours for internet bandwidth and due to a few members of this family working from home, there is throttling on internet connectivity between users.

Is there any product or method that could be used to implement some redundancy to a 4G broadband connection. For example, could we attach multiple antenna SMA's to our home and then join them into some networking box that could intelligently route the traffic through the box, so if one mast goes down, the other one can pick up the slack?

Alternative ideas are also welcome.

Comment: 40Mbps down is decent for up to 4 users, as long as the upstream is decent (10Mbps should be plenty). If you're having a hard time sharing that, you're most likely hitting bufferbloat, not a lack of bandwidth.

Comment: I'll have a look into the bufferbloat but knowing the area, I would suspect the issue would be on the mast side because it is attached to someones barn down the road.

Any tips on pointing at multiple masts at the same time for redundancy?